# How to Extend the Two Arrays in angualrjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to merge the 2 arrays. Arrays get from two different Apis. I use the both concat and extend but not getting properly.

```
$scope.notifications1=ComboService.getcomboNote();
console.log($scope.notifications1)
$scope.notifications2=ComboService.getofferNote();
console.log($scope.notifications2)
```

Response of $scope.notifications1 in Console

```
Array[1]
0:Resource
__v:0
_id:"57564ecea635e6695238cebc"
createdAt:"2016-06-07T04:34:22.235Z"
defaultmainprice:250
defaultofferprice:251
isDeleted:false
itemcode:"C101"
itemdescription:"Combo123"
itemname:"Combo123"
itemstock:0
itemtype:"combos"
modifiedAt:"2016-06-07T04:34:22.235Z"
__proto__:Object
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
length:1
```

Response of $scope.notifications1 in Console

```
Array[1]
0:Resource
__v:0
_id:"5774b69781478fbaee51cdbf"
createdAt:"2016-06-30T06:05:11.619Z"
defaultmainprice:10
defaultofferprice:5
isDeleted:false
itemcode:"10000111"
itemdescription:"Offer1"
itemname:"Offer1"
itemstock:0
itemtype:
"offers"
modifiedAt:"2016-06-30T06:05:11.619Z"
__proto__:Object
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
length:1
```

i use the concat like this

```
$scope.notifications = $scope.notifications1.concat($scope.notifications2)
```

i use the extend  like this

```
 $scope.notifications = angular.extend($scope.notifications1,$scope.notifications2)
```

But not getting properly. please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For deep copy you need to use [merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge).

Comment: $scope.notifications= angular.merge($scope.notifications1,$scope.notifications2) it reurns only $scope.notifications1. i think merge,extend only for objects. type is object only in reference

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube add the required expected output to your question.. also add a plunker of what you are trying to do..